# Как вывести slider slick на Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, slick.js

```
<?php 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'awax_style');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'awax_scripts' );

function awax_style() {
wp_enqueue_style('main_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css'); 
wp_enqueue_style('slick_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick.css');    
}

function awax_scripts() {


    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick_script', get_template_directory_uri() .'assets/js/slick.min.js', array(jquery), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'assets/js/script.js', array(jquery), 'null', true );

}

?>
```

Не работает slick slider, возможно есть ошибка в подключении скриптов в function.php?

Comment: `array(jquery)` должно быть `array('jquery')`, ну и слеш перед `assets/js/slick.min.js` забыли, а то в стилях есть, а тут нет.

Comment: ох, спасибо! а то смотрю и не вижу.